# How to fix height size in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, view, expo, height

I'm using React Native Expo, and I encountered an error when trying to set the size of my Viewer to fit the selection menu and number input.

View Code:

```js
<View style={{ 
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: "black",
  width: "100%"
}}>

<SelectList
  setSelected={(val) => setSelected(val)} 
  data={data} 
  save="value"
  placeholder="Produto"
/>
<TextInput
  style={{ width: "50%" }}
  label="Quantia"
  returnKeyType="done"
  value={delivery}
  onChangeText={(text) => setDelivery(text)}
/>
</View>
```

App Image ( the black background is for testing, just to know how much space is occupied by the View )
https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/873959321376018462/1087615947638050847/Screenshot_20230321-025022_Expo_Go.jpg?width=224&height=473

What can I do to make the background black only in the menu and in the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove the `flex: 1` on the `View` that contains the `SelectList` and the `TextInput`. The property `flex` define how your items fill the available space. Your code will seem like this:

```
<View style={{
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: "black",
  width: "100%"
}}>
  <SelectList
    setSelected={(val) => setSelected(val)} 
    data={data} 
    save="value"
    placeholder="Produto"
  />
  <TextInput
    style={{ width: "50%" }}
    label="Quantia"
    returnKeyType="done"
    value={delivery}
    onChangeText={(text) => setDelivery(text)}
  />
</View>
```

I suggest you read the documentation about [Layout with FlexBox](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox). For this case, you can use the Expo Playground code example in the [Flex section](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flexbox#flex) to see how the property works.

Answer (score 0):

you are giving BgColor property to whole container insted you need to give bgcolor style to InnerView which holds TextInput Property and SelectList!

Is just that only the thing or you are looking for any other result?

```js
<View style={{ 
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: "100%"
    }}>

    <SelectList
      setSelected={(val) => setSelected(val)} 
      data={data} 
      save="value"
      placeholder="Produto"
      style={{backgroundColor:'#000'}}
    />
    <TextInput
      style={{ width: "50%",backgroundColor:'#000'}}
      label="Quantia"
      returnKeyType="done"
      value={delivery}
      onChangeText={(text) => setDelivery(text)}
    />  
    </View>
```

Comment: ping me if you are looking for something else ,please make sure to provide your expected result before your problem! so you can get exact result you want

Comment: I want this background to "be reduced" to the size of the TextInput and the Menu, as the current mode is leaving the buttons and texts extremely separated, since everything should be centralized in the application

Comment: i have made certain changes to codesnippet ! is it like this?